# Access Parent DataItem in Nested ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listview, nested

So I've got two listviews; one nested inside the other.

The parent is being bound to a collection of objects that contain fields such as MaxPrice, MinPrice, and SuggestedProducts.

The nested one is being bound to the SuggestedProducts collection of the parent item.

How could I reference MaxPrice and MinPrice in the nested listview?  Is it even possible?

If you need any clarification, leave me a comment and I'll update my question.

Thanks!

Edit:  This is an ASP.NET ListView

Comment: Which `ListView`: ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SuggestedProduct class would have a reference back to its parent class X (so you'd have a bidrectional data model: `X has a collection of SuggestedProducts and SuggestedProduct has an object reference to X`) you could give SuggestedProduct properties like `MinPrice { get {return parentX.MinPrice;} }` (and perhaps also set) and then use `Eval("MinPrice")` (and perhaps also Bind) in your nested ListView.

Just as an idea in case that modification of your class model is a real and easy option.

Comment: Very good point, but the actual DataModel is a bit convoluted under the covers.  What I'm actually binding to is a custom object that is created strictly for databinding (i.e. i take a whole bunch of other info, and then assemble it all together into the object that is being bound).  Unfortunately, I don't have a way to go back upstream on this one.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue and I found another solution that I would like to share.

From the `ItemDataBound` event on the child nested `ListView` you can get the reference from the parent doing something like this:

```
ListViewDataItem CurrentParentItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item.Parent.Parent.Parent;
ParentObject parentObject = CurrentParentItem.DataItem as ParentObject
//Then you can access to parentObject.MaxPrice & parentObject.MinPrice
```

Hope this help people with the same problem

Comment: Not sure about the reason for the down vote but this was probably the nicest solution. Was working on a similar issue with a repeater but same logic applies.

Comment: I agree. I was looking for similar solution, and first line helped me to find solution. I guess some are expecting copy/paste and anything else is out of the question :P

Comment: Definitely got me going on the right track. (There was one too many `.parent` in my case. Thanks. (6 Years later...still using WebForms)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hack: 
http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/536803-finding-parent-control-value-nested-datalist-c

Answer (score 1):

If you have been set DataKeyNames in the parent, then you can access it like this

```
((ListView)Container.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent).DataKeys[((ListViewDataItem)Container.Parent.Parent.Parent).DataItemIndex][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK; I've got a solution in place, but I'll leave this open for a bit in case anybody can come up with a better one.

Basically, I'm taking the MinPrice and MaxPrice values and dumping them into a HiddenField outside of the nested ListView.

Then, inside the nested one, I'm drilling up (Container.Parent), finding the HiddenField, and then extracting its value.